# HandlebarsJS How to create registerHelper which checks for strings inside JSON

Tags: handlebars.js

I want to create a registerHelper which checks for specific strings inside my JSON file, but somehow I cant get it to work.

So, my JSON returns (just example data, but structure is correct):

```
links : {
   name: "abc",
   href: "some url"
 },
 {
   name: "def"
   href: "some url"
 }
 {
   name: "ghi"
   href: "some url"
 }
 {
   name: "jkl"
   href: "some url"
 }
 and so on...
```

So, based on the name, i want to display different HTML content, so I tried to create a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('specific', function(specs, options) {
    if("abc" || "jkl"){
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

and the html:

```
{{#specific links}}
  <h1>blablab</h1>
{{/specific}}
```

So I have 2 issues:

1) the check doesnt work and
2) if the condition is false, the html should not be displayed

How can I achieve that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` on the second line of your helper is the issue. You aren't comparing your name values to the string literals "abc" or "jkl", you're just asking if those string literals are truthy (which they are), so the condition will always pass no matter what, causing your HTML to always be displayed.

Instead it should read:

```
if(spec.name === "abc" || spec.name === "jkl"){
```

Then you will actually be comparing the name values to the strings as intended.